# Relationship field for navigation menu

Tags: relationships, navigation

I need to create a 'megamenu' with a page title and a summary for each menu item. The only way I can think of doing this is to create a channel entry for the menu and use a relationship field for each item. Is this a good/bad idea? Or is there a better way of doing it?

Comment: Why not to use GRID?

Comment: Yes, I would probably use both Grid and Relationship

Answer (score 1):

Many URLs with summaries in `<UL> <LI>` structure, No doubt channel entry is needed. You can use both Relationships and GRID to accomplish the megamenu needs.

(As there are several plugins available in devote ee But I don't think they will match megamenu criteria so no other options except channel with GRID and Relationships)